# How to Call DB2 Table Valued Function from EF Core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, db2

I am using ASP.NET core 3.1 with EF Core with DB2 AS400 database. I have created a table value function which looks like this

```
CREATE FUNCTION ABELIBLE.TVFBOEGETSHIPMENTS ( 
    STARTDATE DATE , 
    ENDDATE DATE , 
    ADDRESSCODE CHAR(9) ) 
    RETURNS TABLE ( 
    "ID" INTEGER , 
    JOBNUMBER CHAR(9) , 
    CUSTOMERREFERENCE CHAR(18) , 
    CONSIGNEENAME CHAR(30) , 
    CREATEDDATE DATE , 
    AIRPORTOFORIGIN CHAR(3) , 
    AIRPORTOFARRIVAL CHAR(3) , 
    AIRPORTOFDESTINATION CHAR(3) , 
    COUNTRYOFDESTINATION CHAR(3) , 
    ADDRESSCODE CHAR(9) , 
    CONSIGNMENTNUMBER CHAR(25) )   
    LANGUAGE SQL 
    SPECIFIC ABELIBLE.TVFBOEGETSHIPMENTS 
    NOT DETERMINISTIC 
    READS SQL DATA 
    CALLED ON NULL INPUT 
    SET OPTION  ALWBLK = *ALLREAD , 
    ALWCPYDTA = *OPTIMIZE , 
    COMMIT = *NONE , 
    DECRESULT = (31, 31, 00) , 
    DYNDFTCOL = *NO , 
    DYNUSRPRF = *USER , 
    SRTSEQ = *HEX   
    RETURN 
        SELECT 
                ROW_NUMBER ( ) OVER ( ORDER BY EMJOBN DESC ) , 
                A . EMJOBN , 
                A . EMCREF , 
                A . EMOSNM , 
                DATE ( TIMESTAMP_FORMAT ( DIGITS ( A . EMCRTD ) , 'DDMMYY' ) ) , 
                A . EMAOFO , 
                A . EMAOFA , 
                A . EMAOFD , 
                A . EMCOFD , 
                A . EMUKCD , 
                A . EMRPRT 
                FROM DTALIBLE . EMASTER A WHERE A . EMPSFT = 'Y' AND A . EMUKCD = ADDRESSCODE AND 
                ( DATE ( TIMESTAMP_FORMAT ( DIGITS ( A . EMCRTD ) , 'DDMMYY' ) ) >= STARTDATE AND DATE ( TIMESTAMP_FORMAT ( DIGITS ( A . EMCRTD ) , 'DDMMYY' ) ) <= ENDDATE )  ;
```

I am able to get results in DBeaver for this function using this statement

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE(ABELIBLE.TVFBOEGETSHIPMENTS('2020-05-27', '2020-05-27','MUL0044'))
```

However I am unable to call the Function from EF Core. My code to make the call looks like so:

[image]

This is the error I am getting:
[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Please do not use images that contain plain text. The reason is that image contents are not searchable and images are awkward to reference/quote.

Instead, just copy the plain text of your code or error-message into your question.

Your first image show that your query in your code (with incorrect syntax) differs from the query given to DBeaver (with correct syntax). Resolve that first.

The Db2-server rejects your incorrect syntax by throwing SQL0104N. You can lookup these codes in the [Db2-for-i knowledge center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_74/rzaii/rzaiiodbc36.htm). The explanations often help if you take the time to study them.

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried the statement as per DBeaver and I was getting unidentified token "(" hence I have modified the statement.

Answer (score -1):

Figured it out.The below works its to do with how the statement is formatted.

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE ( ABELIBLE.TVFBOEGETSHIPMENTS ( '2020-05-27', '2020-05-27','MUL0044' ) )";
            var Shipments = _appDbContext.Shipments.FromSql(sql);
            return Shipments;
```